# Getting original object after piping via Out-GridView

Tags: powershell

I need to show a list of file names **without paths** and open the selected file.

I can get it to work with full paths:

`Get-ChildItem *.txt -Recurse | Sort-Object Name| Out-GridView -PassThru | Invoke-Item`

But when I try to show only the file names it fails:

`Get-ChildItem *.txt -Recurse | Sort-Object Name| Select-Object Name | Out-GridView -PassThru | Invoke-Item`

By piping it through Get-Member I understand that `Select-Object Name` striped all non-Name properties. So how can I trace the original file object from what I got from GridView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use the [`DefaultDisplayPropertySet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/defining-default-member-sets-for-objects?view=powershell-7) property of the hidden [`PSStandardMembers`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/psstandardmembers-the-stealth-property/) set for this:

```
$defaultDisplayPropertySet = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSPropertySet('DefaultDisplayPropertySet',[string[]]@('Name'))
$PSStandardMembers = [System.Management.Automation.PSMemberInfo[]]@($defaultDisplayPropertySet)

Get-ChildItem *.txt -Recurse | Select-Object * |
ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Add-Member MemberSet PSStandardMembers $PSStandardMembers; $_
} | Out-Gridview -PassThru | Select-Object FullName
```

- `Get-ChildItem *.txt` has a default display propery set of: `LastWriteTime`, `Length`, `Name`
- `Select-Object *` strips off the complete property set (displays all properties)
- `Add-Member MemberSet PSStandardMembers $PSStandardMembers` adds a new **display** set with just the `Name` property and keeps the rest of the properties hidden
- `Select-Object FullName` reveals the hidden `FullName` property

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that the Invoke-Item needs the path and not only the filename.
You could store the get-childitem in a temporary variable:

```
$tmp = Get-ChildItem *.txt -Recurse | Sort-Object Name
$tmp | Select-Object Name | Out-GridView -PassThru
$tmp | Invoke-Item
```

Is that what you wanted? Please let me know if it worked, and if it did please mark my post as the answer. :)